# Django: cannot import name 'url_patterns'

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a weird edge-case where I need to use the data stored in urls.py within a view, but since the urls.py file imports the view, I am getting a circular import error when I try to import the url data into the view.

```
cannot import name 'url_patterns'
```

Does Django have any way of grabbing all the url patterns within a view that could circumvent this error?  The fact that the reverse() function exists indicates that it might.

Comment: The views import the url? Can't you import locally?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "import locally"?

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this typically (well it depends a bit), by importing the `urls` in your view(s) *locally*. Like:

```
# urls.py

import someapp.views

url_patterns = [
    url('some_url/', someapp.views.some_view),
]
```

and then import the urls in the views like:

```
# views.py

def some_view(request):
    from someapp.urls import url_patterns
    # ...
    # do something with urlpatterns
    # return response
    pass
```

We here thus postpone the importing of the `urls.py` in the views, until the view function is actually called. By that time both the `views.py` and `urls.py` are (usually) already loaded. You can however not *call* the view in the `views.py` directly, since then the import is done before the `urls.py` is loaded.

Note that usually you do *not* have to import `url_patterns`, and you can use `reverse(..)` etc. to obtain a URL that corresponds to a view function (even passing parameters into a dictionary, etc.). So I really advice to look for Django tooling to handle URLs.

Comment: Ah, okay, right.  Ordinarily that does work, but that was the first thing I tried, and in this particular situation, it results in the same error.  Also, in this case, using reverse doesn't work, because I am trying to output the url list to a dynamically-generated javascript file that needs to have its own record of what the url patterns are.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer:

```
from django.urls import get_resolver
url_patterns = set(v[1] for k,v in get_resolver(None).reverse_dict.items())
```